# Bounded convergence theorem: is the limit function bounded?

Tags: integration, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm self-studying Durrett (2010). There, he states the Bounded convergence theorem as follows:

> Let $E$ be a set with $\mu(E)<\infty$. Suppose $f_n$ vanishes on $E^c$, $|f_n(x)|\leq M$, and $f_n\to f$ in measure. Then
>   $$
> \int f\;d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\;d\mu.
> $$

The proof appears to employ the fact that $f$ itself vanishes on $E^c$ and $|f(x)|\leq M$. Are these last two facts implied by the premise of the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that $|f(x)| \le M$ is not satisfied a.e. and pick $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ such that if $G = \{|f(x)| \ge M + \epsilon\}$ then $\mu(G) \ge \delta$. Now notice that

$$
0 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(\{|f(x) - f_n(x)| \ge \epsilon\}) 
\ge \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(\{|f(x)| - |f_n(x)| \ge \epsilon\}) \ge \mu(G) \ge \delta.
$$

You can apply the same reasoning restricting your attention to $E^c$ with $M = 0$ to show that $f$ vanishes a.e. on $E^c$.